# Deja-Dup/Duplicity Python Error

Tags: python, backup, deja-dup

Hope someone can help out ...

So my Ubuntu laptop was a bit shoddy, occasional program crashes etc, so I decided to rebuild.

- I ran a backup to my NAS using Deja-Dup (I backup weekly)
- I downloaded Ubuntu 17.10 (current latest version) and reinstalled Ubuntu from USB stick.
- I installed `duplicity` & `python-gi` (`sudo apt install duplicity python-gi`)
- I tried to restore my backup (In fact I tried to restore a few but all fail with same problem)

The reinstall fails with the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1546, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1540, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1391, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1468, in do_backup
    restore(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 731, in restore
    restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 560, in Write_ROPaths
    for ropath in rop_iter:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 523, in integrate_patch_iters
    for patch_seq in collated:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 389, in yield_tuples
    setrorps(overflow, elems)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 378, in setrorps
    elems[i] = iter_list[i].next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 121, in difftar2path_iter
    tarinfo_list = [tar_iter.next()]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 339, in next
    self.set_tarfile()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 333, in set_tarfile
    self.current_fp = self.fileobj_iter.next()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 767, in get_fileobj_iter
    backup_set.volume_name_dict[vol_num],
KeyError: 1
```

What gives?

Comment: Sorry, 1 thing to add.  It makes no difference whether I try to recover the backup taken today, or the backup from a week ago.  It also doesn't matter whether I try to recover a single file, directory or the entire backup.

Comment: Update - seems this may have something to do with GnuGPG.  Ignoring Deja-Dup and using duplicity via the cli to restore a backup, duplicity requests a GnuGPG key.  As my backups are stored on a local NAS I backup without encryption.  If I try to recover using the --no-encryption option I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I had problems with Duplicity & Python on 17.10, I find 18.04 alpha better. Probably because it's sourced from Debian Buster. 
Anyways I would try one of the other front ends to rsync - I've found that since deja-dup uses rsync too, that other apps can usually access the same archive. Try 'Lucky Backup' or 'GRSync'. I've used the latter to recover deja-dup encrypted files before, so I'm sure it'll work fine on a non-encrypted archive. HTH!

Comment: I may be being totally daft here but ... I have GRsync (used to copy stuff to/from my NAS.  GRsync copies the duplicity archives, it doesn't uncompress/restore them in the same way that duplicity does. Right?

Comment: Pretty sure it does @Marcus W., they both are simply front ends to rsync a generic format. Can you work on a copy of the archives?